# OpenGL: efficient way to read sparce pixel data from many framebuffer textures?

Tags: c++, opengl, gpu

I'm writing a program that uses the GPU to calculate stuff, and I want to read data from the framebuffers to be used in my client code.  The framebuffers I'm using are about 40 textures, all 1024x1024 in size, all of which contain data that needs read, but only very sparcely, like 50 or so pixels in arbitrary x/y coordinates from each texture.  Using glReadPixels for each texture, for each frame, is proving too costly for me to do though...

I only need to read a few select pixels from each texture, is there a way to quickly gather their data without needing to download every entire texture from the GPU?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds fairly expensive no matter how you slice it. A couple of approaches come to mind:

- What I would try first is `glReadPixels()`, but with using a PBO. Bind a buffer large enough to hold all the pixels to the `GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER` target, and then submit the `glReadPixels()` calls, with offsets to place the results in distinct sections of the buffer. Then call `glMapBufferRange()` to read back the values.
- An alternate approach is that you copy all the pixels you want to read into a single texture. You could use `glBlitFramebuffer()` or `glCopyTexSubImage2D()`. Then use a single `glReadPixels()` or `glGetTexImage()` call to get all the data from this texture.

Both of these approaches should result in about the same amount of work and synchronization overhead. But one or the other could be more efficient, depending on which paths in the driver are better optimized.

As the earlier answer already suggested, I would make *very* sure that you really need this, and there isn't any way to keep and process the data on the GPU. Any time you read back data, you introduce synchronization between GPU and CPU, which is mostly harmful to performance.

Comment: Option 2 appears to be the faster of the two for me, and works fairly well!  (needing to withdraw the values is unavoidable unfortunately)

Answer (score 2):

Do you have any restrictions on what OpenGL version you can use? If not, it sounds like you should look into compute shaders. You say that you are calculating data, so I assume that you are "abusing" the rendering pipeline for your application, especially the fragment shader, and store fragment data in the framebuffer that is interpreted as something else than color.

If this is the case, then all you need is a shader storage buffer and an atomic counter. At some point right now you are deciding that fragment (x, y, z [z being the texture index]) should have value v. So in your compute shader, you do your calculation as you would in the fragment shader, but as output, you store a tuple (x, y, z, v). You store this tuple in the shader storage buffer at the index of the atomic counter which you increment after each written element. In the end, you have your data stored compactly in the buffer and only need to read back these elements. The exact number is the value the atomic counter holds after termination. Download the buffer with glGetBufferSubData into an array of location-value pairs, iterate over it and do your CPU magic.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to copy the data from the GPU to the CPU memory, there is no way (AFAIK) around using glReadPixels.

Depending on what platform you're using, and the specific of your programs, you can try several optimizations, using FBOs:

- Copy only part of the texture, assuming you know the locations of the pixels. Note that in most cases it still faster to copy the entire texture instead of issuing several small reads
- If you don't need 32 bit textures, you can render to a lower color resolution. The specific depends on your platform extensions.
- Maybe you don't really need to copy the pixels since you plan to use them as a texture input to the next stage? In that case you copy the pixels directly on the GPU using glCopyTexImage2D